# Android approach to accessing a windows share on local network

Tags: android, networking, android-studio

I have been searching google for a tutorial or guide on how to access a windows shared folder on a local network on android studio, but all i seem to find is httpclient which seems to be only for internet addresses.
I would like to code an app to be able to access a text file on a shared computer using its ip address. For example `\\192.168.23.3\shares\data.txt`

Can someone Please point me in the right direction.